# Splitting single file to multiple file

Tags: java, regex

I was given a `SQL` file that consists of more than 20,000 lines. The `sql` consists of procedures, ddl and dml. I finding a 'faster' way to split the file...

So I was thinking of creating a script that split the content according to the functions. Below are my regex:

```
String sp_regex = "(CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE) .+(SHOW ERRORS;)$";
String insert_regex = "(INSERT INTO) .+(SHOW ERRORS;)$";
String delete_regex = "(DELETE FROM) .+([)];)$";
String table_regex = "(CREATE TABLE) .+([)];)$";
```

But none of the regex working. The content didn't split at all. What is the problem with my regex?

Sample SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."SP" (
......
);
/
SHOW ERRORS;

CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE" (
......
);

INSERT INTO "SCHEMA"."TABLE" ( ...... ) VALUES ( "......" );

DELETE FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE" WHERE ..... = "....";
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how your file looks like and how you're using the regex. My guess is that you haven't compiled the regex using the `Pattern.MULTILINE` option, and therefore `$` only matches at the very end of the string, not at the end of each line.

Comment: I added the sample sql format in the file, @TimPietzcker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow the `.` to match newlines and allow the `$` to match line endings (not just EOF). If you do that, you will also need to make the `+` quantifier lazy in order to tell it to stop matching at the earliest possible point:

```
String sp_regex = "(?sm)(CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE) .+?(SHOW ERRORS;)$";
String insert_regex = "(?sm)(INSERT INTO) .+?(SHOW ERRORS;)$";
String delete_regex = "(?sm)(DELETE FROM) .+?([)];)$";
String table_regex = "(?sm)(CREATE TABLE) .+?([)];)$";
```

You need to test this thoroughly - lines that don't match any of these regexes will simply be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Have to test thoroughly, because there are different types of coding styles in the sql. By the way, thanks for the tips, it works better now. Still editing the regex.

Comment: I used `Pattern` and `Matcher` instead of `split()`, meanwhile `split()` I used for the `"schema"."[name]"` to get the `name` for the sql later. Thanks Tim.